# Lookup value from row in column in another file, fill column with value from other file

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files:

File A: Current product list with brand (Marke:), article (Titel:) and price (Preis:), in xlsx.
This file contains the following headers and contains around 50.000 row values:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marke: | Titel: | Preis: |
| ABC | DEF | 123 |
| ... | ... | ... |

File B: Historical price information archive for all brands, articles and prices, in xlsx.
This file contains the following headers and can be more than a million row values:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 | Col 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marke: | Titel: | Preis: | Count: | Mean: | High: | Low: |
| ABC | DEF | 123 | 10 | 110 | 200 | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

What do I want to achieve?
I want to fill File A with the detailed pricing information from File B that is in Col 5-7.

The identifier is the column "Titel:". Their can be x-times the same "Titel:" in File B. In this case, just take the first match, because in every iteration of "Titel:" in File B the pricing information in Col. 5-7 is the same.

I cannot simply use File B, because File A is updated every hour and only contains the relevant new data for the day. File B is a historical and large archive. I want to add the historic pricing perspective to file A, so that mean, high and low prices are available there. It can happen that row values from File A occure x-times in file B or may not be even be present to date. File B is only updated every week. So in case File B does not have the information, it should fill up with "not available".

Then I want to save it as File C.

File C expected outcome:
Added column information from File B to all 50.000 row values taken from Fila A.

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marke: | Titel: | Preis: | Mean: | High: | Low: |
| ABC | DEF | 123 | 110 | 200 | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Picture of table structure:

[Check table structure for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krY78.png)

I have tried several methods with pandas, from .merge as well as .map, but was not successful. Maybe I did not get it right.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, we will go through the following steps:

1. read data from files and generate dataframes: `File_A.xlsx` -> `df_A`; `File_B.xlsx` -> `df_B`
2. In `df_B`, drop rows has duplicated values of column `Titel`, except the first row. In other words, only the unique or first row of same `Titel` will be kept in the dataframe. Let's use `df_B_dropped` to name the returned dataframe after the dropping operation.
3. Merge `df_A` and `df_B_dropped`

Let's hands on the steps

1. We skip the read data codes. We use pseudo data to make up `df_A`

```
Marke,Titel,Preis
ABC,abc,123.12
DEF,def,456.45
UVW,uvw,789.78
XYZ,xyz,321.32
```

and `df_B`

```
Marke,Titel,Preis,Count,Mean,High,Low
GWTR,gwtr,897.75,5799,99.88,569.81,17.42
CCCU,cccu,411.77,3570,284.91,1555.82,80.58
ABC,abc,123.12,9095,95.71,333.43,33.68
ABC,abc,123.12,8441,218.37,843.24,63.65
DEF,def,456.45,9250,259.09,750.22,53.34
ABC,abc,123.12,1233,612.06,2792.8,129.86
ABC,abc,123.12,2346,280.98,1421.14,232.03
EREA,erea,167.37,7359,656.93,1532.24,140.1
MTKR,mtkr,963.3,7467,171.24,959.91,33.34
DEF,def,456.45,7842,35.57,151.81,10.18
GLZL,glzl,271.62,7117,284.47,655.08,69.83
XYZ,xyz,321.32,2914,401.98,2152.2,311.57
WOEN,woen,34.97,3690,579.98,1808.21,235.26
DEF,def,456.45,8510,246.77,945.39,46.09
ATHX,athx,22.04,960,396.38,1455.06,191.68
XYZ,xyz,321.32,3019,1.53,4.39,0.4
DEF,def,456.45,7305,526.25,1517.18,174.45
YGSM,ygsm,803.11,7745,138.88,515.4,29.1
DEF,def,456.45,8552,67.31,372.26,12.44
JTLY,jtly,371.62,3155,137.24,336.41,40.87
XYZ,xyz,321.32,9591,49.8,235.0,20.7
ZGVV,zgvv,138.23,8383,88.6,213.36,19.82
ABC,abc,123.12,7187,425.77,1737.66,280.92
XYZ,xyz,321.32,1044,359.66,1691.45,69.49
XYZ,xyz,321.32,9585,294.07,1269.86,136.43
```

The above data of `df_B` (25 rows x 7 columns) consists of 10 irrelevant random rows and 15 rows related to `df_A`.

Please note that there are four values of `Titel`：`abc`, `def`, `uvw`, `xyz`. Only the `uvw` cannot be found in `df_B`, each of the other three has five rows in `df_B`.

Therefor, the final result should be
[image]

2. Drop the rows with duplicated values in 'Titel' in `df_B`:

```
df_B_dropped = df_B.drop_duplicates(subset='Titel', keep='first')
```

Please note that the parameter `keep='first'` which keeps the first rows with values in 'Titel' as `abc`, `def` or `xyz`.

The result, `df_B_dropped` must have only 13 rows.

3. Merge

```
df_C = df_A.merge(
    df_B_dropped,
    how='left', left_on=['Marke', 'Titel', 'Preis'],
    right_on=['Marke', 'Titel', 'Preis']
)

# write 'not available' into Nan cells
df_C.fillna('not available', inplace=True)
```

The result is
[image]

The final step is to write the `df_C` into a file `File_C.xlsx`